# RewriteRule adding extra url params if directory exists

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got a couple of rewrite's set up in my .htacess. It's currently set up to point all files to /core/index.php which is fine.

I use svn:external to check out core files and features into the project. Now the problem arises when i have a directory with the same name as my feature for example i check out "property" into a folder called "property". I've added a rule so that if the file exists then ignore it and use the same behaviour as above but when i try 
*/property* it changes the url to */property/?url=property*
but when i do */property/* it remains as is which is what i'm after.

I'm nearly there but just can't figure out how to not show /?url=property when the url doesn't have a / after property(or what ever file exists) (*/property/*).

Here is my .htaccess - please bear with me on this re-writes are new ground for me and this may not even be correct. Basically below i have 2 rules, the first for all files that don't exist and then second on is for files that do exist - but i want to ignore and use the same behaviour as the first rule.

```
   #re-write for file that don't exist
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On

      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /core/index.php?url=$1 [L]
    </IfModule>

    #re-write for file that do exist
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On

      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /core/index.php?url=$1 [L]

    </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this line **on top of your .htaccess**:

```
 DirectorySlash On

 ## Adding a trailing slash
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
 RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
```

This will always add a slash if request is for a directory and you will be able to avoid this problem.

Comment: Q1. Is this the only .htaccess or do you have another? Q2. Is this the only code in this .htaccess? If you have some other code then please post it in question? Q3. What is location of above .htaccess?

Comment: No other .htaccess files exist and this is the only code in there. It's located in the root.

Comment: OK I have added an `Adding a trailing slash` rule. Make sure this rule in on top before other rule and then retest.

Comment: Excellent this works, thank you. So this basically says if the file does't exist, there is no / at the end, then add the slash?